# Using ~/.vim/scripts.vim to detect a file's type

Tags: vim

I'm trying to solve an annoying issue with the Vim editor where Bash scripts (not SH scripts) are assigned the file type `sh` and not `bash`.  (For my own purposes, I want the filetype to be `bash` and not `sh`.)

[*Note 1*. Within the Vim editor, if I type
 `:setfiletype CTRL+d`
or
 `:echo getcompletion('ba', 'filetype')`
the file type `bash` is listed among the available/recognized file types. *—end note*]

[*Note 2*. I'm working on a Linux host. For the discussion that follows, <strike>these two Vim configuration files **DO NOT** exist: `~/.vimrc` or `~/.gvimrc`</strike> file `~/.vimrc` exists and it contains only one command:
 `filetype on`
I do not have a file named `~/.gvimrc`. *—end note*]

---

**Scenario 1)** When I use Vim to edit a file whose file extension is `.bash`, I want Vim to assign the file type `bash`, not `sh`, to the file's buffer.  I solved this by creating file `~/.vim/filetype.vim` shown in Listing 1:

*Listing 1. ~/.vim/filetype.vim*

```
" ~/.vim/filetype.vim
if exists("did_load_filetypes")
  finish
endif
augroup filetypedetect
  au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.bash let b:is_bash = 1 | setfiletype bash
augroup END
```

---

**Scenario 2)** When I use Vim to edit a text file whose first line is any of the following,

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
#!/bin/env bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

I want Vim to assign the file type `bash`, not `sh`, to the file's buffer.

**This is the scenario that I'm struggling to find a solution for, and would like some assistance with.**

[*Note 1*. For the discussion that follows, I removed file `~/.vim/filetype.vim` so that it cannot assign the filetype `bash` to a file buffer's filetype property. *—end note*]

The Vim help topic [new-filetype-scripts](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#new-filetype-scripts) describes a procedure for creating a user-defined Vim script (`~/.vim/scripts.vim`), and it seems to me that this solution should work.  However, when I try this approach, the Vim script doesn't have any effect.  When Vim opens a text file whose first line—i.e., whose shebang line `#!`—is any of the four lines shown above, Vim always assigns the file type `sh` to the file's buffer.

For what it's worth, I tried a "brute force" approach to setting the file type to `bash` as shown in Listing 2 and Listing 3, but Vim ignored this and it set the file's type to `sh`:

*Listing 2. "Brute force" version of ~/.vim/scripts.vim (method 1)*

```
" ~/.vim/scripts.vim
setfiletype bash
```

*Listing 3. "Brute force" version of ~/.vim/scripts.vim (method 2)*

```
" ~/.vim/scripts.vim
set filetype=bash
```

The Vim help topic [new-filetype-scripts](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#new-filetype-scripts) expressly states,

> Your scripts.vim is loaded before the default checks for file types, which means that your rules override the default rules in $VIMRUNTIME/scripts.vim.

So, I'm not understanding why Vim is setting the file buffer's filetype property to `sh` and not `bash`.

And for what it's worth, I've tried creating a vim script file that is based on the example shown in the Vim help topic [new-filetype-scripts](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#new-filetype-scripts) (see Listing 4), but that version also does not set the filetype property to `bash`:

*Listing 4. ~/.vim/scripts.vim example based on the Vim help example **new-filetype-scripts**.*

```
if did_filetype()
    finish
endif
if getline(1) =~# '^#!.*/bin/env\s\&lt;bash\&gt;'
    setfiletype bash
elseif getline(1) =~# '^#!.*/bin/bash'
    setfiletype bash
endif
```

And, of course, I've tried coding the `if` statements' conditional expressions using "exact match" strings, as shown in Listing 5. But like before, the file buffer's filetype property is always set to `sh` and not `bash`:

*Listing 5. ~/.vim/scripts.vim whose if statements use "exact match" conditional expressions.*

```
if did_filetype()
    finish
endif
if getline(1) == '#!/bin/env bash'
    setfiletype bash
elseif getline(1) == '#!/usr/bin/env bash'
    setfiletype bash
elseif getline(1) == '#!/bin/bash'
    setfiletype bash
elseif getline(1) == '#!/usr/bin/bash'
    setfiletype bash
endif
```

So, what am I misunderstanding?  Why doesn't my `~/.vim/scripts.vim` file set the file buffer's filetype property to `bash`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `:help new-filetype-scripts` tells us to:

   ```
   See $VIMRUNTIME/scripts.vim for more examples
   ```

   so let's do just that. The most relevant part of `$VIMRUNTIME/scripts.vim` is this comment:

   ```
   " This file is called by an autocommand for every file that has just been
   " loaded into a buffer.  It checks if the type of file can be recognized by
   " the file contents.  The autocommand is in $VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim.
   ```
2. Somewhere down `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim` (line 2669 of 2959 for me, YMMV) we can find the autocommand in question, which we will call "autocommand A":

   ```
   au BufNewFile,BufRead *
    \ if !did_filetype() && expand("<amatch>") !~ g:ft_ignore_pat
    \ | runtime! scripts.vim | endif
   ```

   which is relatively easy to follow:

   - when the `BufNewFile` or `BufRead` events are fired,
   - whatever their matched value,
   - source all `scripts.vim` files you can find in `:help 'runtimepath`,
   - if no filetype has been set,
   - and if the matched value is not in some default list.

   There is a big problem, here, which is that *autocommand A* is installed **after** that other autocommand (line 2004 for me), which we will call "autocommand B":

   ```
   au BufNewFile,BufRead .bashrc,bashrc,bash.bashrc,.bash[_-]profile,.bash[_-]logout,.bash[_-]aliases,bash-fc[-.],*.ebuild,*.bash,*.eclass,PKGBUILD,APKBUILD call dist#ft#SetFileTypeSH("bash")
   ```

   That is a problem because *autocommand B* is executed first and somewhat stupidly sets the filetype to `sh` via the `dist#ft#SetFileTypeSH("bash")` function. When *autocommand A* kicks in, the filetype has already been set, so `!did_filetype()` is falsy, so the command `runtime! scripts.vim` is not executed.

   Frankly, this seems unnecessarily complicated and that idea of doing `let b:is_bash = 1` instead of actually setting a proper `bash` filetype is *baffling*, to say the least.

   At this point, the only possible conclusion is that `~/.vim/scripts.vim` is very unlikely to ever be sourced automatically, which makes `:help new-filetype-scripts` fundamentally incorrect and your attempted solution flawed-by-design.

   *Sigh*
3. A simple solution is to ignore `:help new-filetype-scripts` and put both your extension logic and your file content logic in the same place:

   ```
   " in ~/.vim/filetype.vim
   if exists("did_load_filetypes")
     finish
   endif
   augroup filetypedetect
     autocmd! BufRead,BufNewFile *.bash let b:is_bash = 1 | setfiletype bash
     autocmd! BufRead,BufNewFile * if getline(1) == '#!/bin/env bash'
         \ | setfiletype bash
         \ | elseif getline(1) == '#!/usr/bin/env bash'
         \ | setfiletype bash
         \ | elseif getline(1) == '#!/bin/bash'
         \ | setfiletype bash
         \ | elseif getline(1) == '#!/usr/bin/bash'
         \ | setfiletype bash
         \ | endif
   augroup END
   ```
4. Bonus points if you open an issue and manage to convince the team to fix that mess.

Answer (score 1):

<del>$VIMRUNTIME/scripts.vim is responsible for delegating to your scripts.vim</del> (need to investigate this – see @romainl’s answer), and it doesn’t run your scripts.vim at all if the filetype is already set.

Following another example in the help file,

> You can also use the already detected file type in your command. For example, to use the file type "mypascal" when "pascal" has been detected:
>
> ```
> au BufRead,BufNewFile * if &ft == 'pascal' | set ft=mypascal | endif
> ```

how about:

```
au! BufRead,BufNewFile *
  \   if &filetype == 'sh' && getline(1) =~# '\v^#!/(usr/)?bin/(env )?bash'
  \ |   set filetype=bash
  \ | endif
```

Comment: "your scripts.vim [doesn't run] if the filetype is already set."  After re-re-reading the Vim help, I think I understand the sequence now. If 'filetype on' is present in ~/.vimrc, Vim uses $VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim to detect the file type.  If Vim fails to detect the file type via $VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim, Vim then tries ~/.vim/scripts.vim (if it exists), followed by $VIMRUNTIME/scripts.vim.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Ry- and @romainl for your useful comments and suggestions, which led me to my own solution.  As suggested by @romainl, my solution uses file `~/.vim/filetype.vim` instead of file `~/.vim/scripts.vim`; see Listing 1 below.

*Listing 1. File ~/.vim/filetype.vim*

```
" ~/.vim/filetype.vim
if exists("did_load_filetypes")
  finish
endif
augroup filetypedetect
  autocmd! BufRead,BufNewFile *.bash let b:is_bash = 1 | setfiletype bash
  autocmd! BufRead,BufNewFile *
    \ if getline(1) =~# '\v^#!/(usr/)?bin/(env[ \t]+)?<bash>'
    \ |   let b:is_bash = 1
    \ |   setfiletype bash
    \ | endif
augroup END
```